# Failing to install ZeroRPC on Ubuntu

Tags: python, node.js, ubuntu, zerorpc

I have been trying to install ZeroRPC on Ubuntu. I have already installed ZeroMQ but while installing ZeroRPC these errors are showing up. I'm basically tying to run a python script in background from node.js which sends JSON object and receives JSON from the python code. Also the python code must always be running in the backend.

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:354:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-21-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/user/node_modules/msgpack
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 

/home/user
`-- python-shell@0.4.0 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/package.json'
npm WARN user No description
npm WARN user No repository field.
npm WARN user No README data
npm WARN user No license field.
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-21-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "zerorpc"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! msgpack@1.0.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the msgpack@1.0.2 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the msgpack package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs msgpack
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls msgpack
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/user/npm-debug.log

npm ERR!     npm bugs msgpack
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls msgpack
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/user/npm-debug.log
```

Failing to install this and stuck at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is about failing to build msgpack, not about zerorpc. Try following what the error message is telling you to do. This will help you to build msgpack successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced the same issue.

I found another answer ([node-gyp rebuild error while installing node modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664985/node-gyp-rebuild-error-while-installing-node-modules)) that helped me get a successful build on my project.

clear your package manager cache

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
```

install node version manager

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

update to v4.3.0 ( have not investigated the significance of this version but it resolved my issue that looked identical to the one above)

```
sudo n 4.3.0
```

install your library

```
sudo npm install zerorpc
```